Installing Standalone Application Packages(.msix and.msixbundle)
I work in an in-house IT department.  We block user access to the Microsoft Store by default due to bandwidth limitations and concerns about users installing non-work related applications without authorization(since MS Store apps can install without local admin permissions).  While we are going to be working on a formal HR-level policy and associated AD group policy limitations to allow some applications(hopefully), at the current juncture, I'm still stuck trying to get an application that is only available on the MS store, which I have acquired the .msix file for, installed on an end user machine.
This has led me down a bit of a rabbit hole.  It appears I already have a dependent package installed, "Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller.msixbundle", on my PC, but I can't install this on the end user PC.  I've tried click-to-run on both the other .msix file and this .msixbundle file as local administrator, running it via command prompt, and via powershell.  Nothing works.
Is there a simple way to install .msix packages on Windows 10 without M$ Store connectivity?

have you reviewed this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/app-installer-root

Are you sure DesktopAppInstaller isn't already installed?  It should be unless you specifically remove it.  Furthermore, what edition of Windows are we talking about, some editions of Windows 10 are limited when it comes to the MS Store to begin with

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
